# Refurbished lenses from Nikon

Tags: nikon, used-equipment

I am interested in purchasing refurbished lenses from Nikon.

From time to time Nikon will release some refurbished items, they are cheaper of course; but, how well can I depend on a refurbished lens? What is a refurbished lens in the first place?

Does being refurbished affect the output? Does it have a defective mechanism that may cause some defects to my camera body and mechanism. How will I know?

Comment: It's not relevant to Nikon, but Canon, USA now includes a one year warranty on refurbished cameras, lenses, and flashes. That's the same as their warranty on new items. All of the refurbished gear I have bought directly from Canon looked brand new. The 5D mark III I bought refurbished had 16 clicks on the shutter when I received it.

Comment: @MichaelClark it is also relevant to Nikon too ... please see the link http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Store/Refurbished-Cameras.page -- and you say that no fear from refurbished items when I can get a warranty.

Comment: So Nikon gives you 90 days on refurbished products.

Comment: refurbished might mean "bought new, used for a day" or something that's been around for a while. Both cases should yield like-new item but cheaper. BTW, what lenses are you specifically talking about?

Comment: @MichaelClark I believe that shutter clicks are recorded in camera's memory, so shutter might have actually 0 clicks if it was replaced. I've seen such thing on Ebay so maybe not true

Comment: @aandreev I guess it is possible, but I've never seen a reconditioned camera with 0 clicks. Most I have seen had anywhere from a handful to a few hundred. I have heard of a few that had upwards of a thousand. Shutters probably go through a bit more QC before they are installed in a camera than some of the other parts, so a shutter failure right out of the box is very rare. The vast majority of refurbished cameras and lenses are either demos, returns from someone who changed their mind, or returns due to a minor defect that passed QC (i.e. a dead/stuck pixel on the LCD screen).

Comment: As far as I know, Amazon sends cameras back to nikon. For just QA or refurbishment idk. I was saying that when Nikon replaced shutters in D600, number of clicks was still the same in camera's memory. Even though shutter's mechanics were basically new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally (I can't speak for Nikon) refurbished equipment is used\broken\defective equipment that has been returned to a manufacturer.

The manufacturer will then refit, clean, and repackage the item to factory specifications (as if it were new) and then sell it at a discounted price.

Refurbished items generally have a shorter warranty, but since they were handled by the manufacturer and returned to factory specifications there is hardly (if ever) a chance of damage to your equipment.

Take a look at the [Nikon USA](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Store/Refurbished-Cameras.page) page for more info on their refurbished equipment.

Comment: in the category of "used", a lot of refurb gear is ex-demo

Comment: I think the greatest danger of damage, whether buying new or refurbished, is when you have it shipped to you. As Roger Cicala of lensrentals.com pointed out in a blog a long time ago, just because the lens is out of adjustment when you receive it doesn't mean it was that way when it left the factory/warehouse/rental facility. Roger's company sales any piece of equipment they own when it has been rented a total of 40 times. That's 80 trips through the UPS grinder, so he knows what he is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what the quality control is like for new lenses - most likely a few specimens are pulled off the line and tested - it's possible that refurbished lenses can generally be be more reliable than new, in that they get more fully bench tested compared to new lenses that go out the door.  I would think a refurb would be *less* likely to have issues with it.  Balance that against a shorter warranty though.